# python regex find matched string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the matched string in a string using regex in Python. The `string` looks like this:

```
band   1 # energy  -53.15719532 # occ.  2.00000000

ion      s      p      d    tot
  1  0.000  0.995  0.000  0.995
  2  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
tot  0.000  0.996  0.000  0.996

band   2 # energy  -53.15719532 # occ.  2.00000000

ion      s      p      d    tot
  1  0.000  0.995  0.000  0.995
  2  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
tot  0.000  0.996  0.000  0.996

band   3 # energy  -53.15719532 # occ.  2.00000000
```

My goal is to find the string after `tot`. So the matched string will be something like:

```
['0.000  0.996  0.000  0.996', 
'0.000  0.996  0.000  0.996']
```

Here is my current code:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'tot\s+(.*?)\n', re.DOTALL)
pattern.findall(string)
```

However, the output gives me:

```
['1  0.000  0.995  0.000  0.995',
 '0.000  0.996  0.000  0.996',
 '1  0.000  0.995  0.000  0.995',
 '0.000  0.996  0.000  0.996']
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want the `DOTALL` flag. Remove it and use [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) instead.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^\s*tot(.*)', re.MULTILINE)
```

This matches all lines that start with `tot`. The rest of the line will be in group 1.

Citing the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), emphasis mine:

> `re.DOTALL`
>
> Make the `'.'` special character match any character at all, **including
>   a newline**; without this flag, `'.'` will match anything except a
>   newline.

Note that you can easily do this without regex.

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        items = filter(None, line.split(" "))
        if items[0] == "tot":
            # etc
```

Comment: This solves my problem. I think I am confused about `DOTALL` and `MUTILINE`. Need to read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using re.DOTALL, which means that the dot "." will match anything, even newlines, in essence finding both "tot"-s and everything that follows until the next newline:

```
                            tot
  1  0.000  0.995  0.000  0.995
```

and

```
tot  0.000  0.996  0.000  0.996
```

Removing re.DOTALL should fix your problem.

Edit:
Actually, the DOTALL flag is not really the issue (though unnecessary). The problem in the pattern is that the \s+ matches the newline. Replacing that with a single space solves that issue:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'tot (.*?)\n')
```

Comment: I think I should change `DOTALL` to `MULTILINE` as @Tomalak suggested

Comment: MULTILINE is not needed here, unless you would want to make use of ^ and $ to match beginning and end of a line, respectively. I have to point out that @Tomalak's solution is cleaner.

Comment: You're right. `\s+` is actually the problem here. I though it only means more than one whitespaces. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative solution using `re.findall` function with specific regex pattern:

```
# str is your inital string
result = re.findall('tot [0-9 .]+(?=\n|$)', str)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['tot  0.000  0.996  0.000  0.996', 'tot  0.000  0.996  0.000  0.996']
```